# Как определить есть ли аргументы у функции

Tags: python

Как из кода узнать есть ли (сколько и какие) параметры у другой функции?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Используйте inspect:

```
import inspect  
def t(a, b, c):  
    pass  

inspect.getargspec(t)
```

Пример вывода:

```
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вот так узнаю можно ли функцию(метод) без параметров запускать.
def check_no_params(funk_name):
 params = inspect.getargspec(funk_name)._asdict()
 if len(params['args']) == len(params['defaults']):
  print('No required args')